# How to draw heatmap with huge data

Tags: d3.js

i want to draw a heatmap base on about 1,100,000 records.
i used [This tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084) to draw my heat map but when i run the code browser crashes and give 'not responsive javascript code ' error.
any idea?

Comment: Use less data or aggregate it into fewer visual elements.

Comment: More context to @LarsKotthoff's comment: There are very few times when drawing a million distinct elements is going to be useful.  On most screens, that means each element is going to be one pixel or smaller.  If you really want to draw a smooth heatmap with pixel-by-pixel resolution, draw it on a `<canvas>`, and be sure to load your data in batches rather than all at once.

Comment: And in particular, even assuming a really high resolution screen, you'll never get good performance with this many elements.